# jQuery Autocomplete Multiple Inputs Highlited

Tags: jquery, input, autocomplete, highlight

i have a problem getting multiple inputs in jquery autocomplete highlited.
The first input get highlited, the second unfortunately not :(

So when i type in Java the word gets bold, but after that when i separate java with a comma and type in another word this gets not bold.

Please Help

```
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var availableTags=["Java","J2ee","Spring","Hibernate","CSS","HTML","Struts","Struts 2","Maven","Maven 2","Spring Roo","Warszawa","JSF 2.0","EJB"];
    $.extend($.ui.autocomplete.prototype, {
        _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
            var term = this.element.val(),
                regex = new RegExp( '(' + term + ')', 'gi' );
            html = item.label.replace( regex , "<b>$&</b>" );
            return $( "<li></li>" ).data( "item.autocomplete", item ).append( $("<a></a>").html(html) ).appendTo( ul );
        }
    });

    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }

    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#tags" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function( request, response ) {
                // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                return false;
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

After a better look at the code, the problem was indeed here:

```
var term = this.element.val(),
    regex = new RegExp( '(' + term + ')', 'gi' );
```

You are getting the full `.val()` of the textbox. Just fix it like this:

```
regex = new RegExp( '(' + extractLast(term) + ')', 'gi' );
```

**EXTRA**

Anyway, it may not be related, but what I usually do to get the bold effect is to compose it in the `source:` function rather than rewriting `_renderItem`. Like this:

```
    source: function (request, response) {
        console.log(request.term);
        var filtered = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, extractLast(request.term));
        var regex = new RegExp('(' + extractLast(request.term) + ')', 'gi' );
        var results = [];
        filtered.forEach(function (item) {
            results.push({ label: item.replace(regex , "<b>$1</b>"), value:item });
        });
        response(results);
    },
    html: true, // see below why this is needed.
```

I have updated the code in the fiddle, it should work now: http://jsfiddle.net/95aH7/1/

**IMPORTANT:** You need to include [jquery.ui.autocomplete.html](http://dev.nemikor.com/jquery-ui-extensions/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js) in your scripts, after you load jQuery UI. Also for the extension to work, you will need to add `html: true` to the autocomplete options (look at the fiddle).

Comment: Tallamaris thanks for you quick respond.

I tried your idea but had no luck :(

Here is the link, to play around.

http://jsfiddle.net/95aH7/

Looking forward to hear from you, Thanks!

Comment: I changed the split to grab commas and whitespaces, and changed the minlength to 2 see on http://jsfiddle.net/95aH7/3/, but this option works only on the first input? how i get minlength = 2 on all inputs?

Comment: minlength is only for the "activation" and is counted for the whole text box. You need to check the length of `extractLast(request.term)` in the source function and eventually return an empty array in that case. See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95aH7/4/

Comment: Added a fix to the original code as well, your `_renderItem()` was just missing a bit. However, this will not also fix the `minLength` to work as you wish; you need to code it into the `source:` function as per my comment above.

Comment: Big THX! I will remember you for payed tasks in the future :)